# Jupyter Notebook: SQL Wildcards in SQL_Magic cell

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook connected to a PostgreSQL database. I'd like to retrieve some data using wildcard lookup (WHERE col_a LIKE '%substr%') but it doesn't work in a cell with sql_magic.

I can execute queries just fine as long as they don't have a wildcard % search.

### Config Cell (match your config)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection_string = '...your db...'
pg_engine = create_engine(connection_string)
```

### sql_magic Cell

```
%reload_ext sql_magic
%config SQL.conn_name = 'pg_engine'
```

### SQL Cell:

```
%%read_sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    select '100' as col_a
) as a
WHERE col_a LIKE '%0%'; -- returns empty, but should have 1 record
```

The query in "SQL Cell" returns 1 row running in pgAdmin, but returns EmptyResult running in the Notebook.

```
Out: <sql_magic.exceptions.EmptyResult at 0x7f5cdeefb240>
```

The problem seems to be with the LIKE statement, since it reads data without the WHERE clause. I tried escaping the % symbols like this:

```
WHERE col_a LIKE '\%0\%';
```

but still got EmptyResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out repeating % acts as an escape, so this code works:

```
%%read_sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    select '100' as col_a
) as a
WHERE col_a LIKE '%%0%%';
```

Comment: another alternative is to use the psycopg2 package to connect (instead of sqlalchemy), then % work fine.